# c++ "Incomplete type not allowed" error accessing class reference information (Circular dependency with forward declaration)

Tags: c++, class, reference, forward-declaration

Had some issues in my code recently surrounding what I now know of as a Circular dependency. In short there are two classes, Player and Ball, which both need to use information from the other. Both at some point in the code will be passed a reference of the other (from another class that will include both .h files).

After reading up on it, I removed the #include.h files from each one and went with forward declaration. This solved the issue of being able to declare the classes in eachother, but I'm now left with an "Incomplete type error" when trying to access a passed reference to the object. There seem to be a few similar examples around, though often mixed with more complex code and hard to narrow down to the basics.

I've rewritten the code in it's simplest form (a skeleton essentially).

Ball.h:

```
class Player;

class Ball {
public:
    Player& PlayerB;
    float ballPosX = 800;
private:

};
```

Player.h:

```
class Ball;

class Player {
public:
    void doSomething(Ball& ball);
private:
};
```

Player.cpp:

```
#include "Player.h"

void Player::doSomething(Ball& ball) {
    ball.ballPosX += 10;                   // incomplete type error occurs here.
}
```

Any help understanding why this is the case would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: `#include "Ball.h"` in Player.cpp

Answer (score 37, accepted):

If you will place your definitions in this order then the code will be compiled

```
class Ball;

class Player {
public:
    void doSomething(Ball& ball);
private:
};

class Ball {
public:
    Player& PlayerB;
    float ballPosX = 800;
private:

};

void Player::doSomething(Ball& ball) {
    ball.ballPosX += 10;                   // incomplete type error occurs here.
}

int main()
{
}
```

The definition of function doSomething requires the complete definition of class Ball because it access its data member.

In your code example module Player.cpp has no access to the definition of class Ball so the compiler issues an error.

Answer (score 30):

`Player.cpp` require the definition of `Ball` class. So simply add `#include "Ball.h"`

**Player.cpp:**

```
#include "Player.h"
#include "Ball.h"

void Player::doSomething(Ball& ball) {
    ball.ballPosX += 10;                   // incomplete type error occurs here.
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is what I had and what caused my "incomplete type error":

```
#include "X.h" // another already declared class
class Big {...} // full declaration of class A

class Small : Big {
    Small() {}
    Small(X); // line 6
}
//.... all other stuff
```

What I did in the file "Big.cpp", where I declared the A2's constructor with X as a parameter is..

#### Big.cpp

```
Small::Big(X my_x) { // line 9 <--- LOOK at this !
}
```

**I wrote "Small::Big" instead of "Small::Small"**, what a dumb mistake..
I received the error "incomplete type is now allowed" for the class X all the time (in lines 6 and 9), which made a total confusion..

Anyways, that is where a mistake can happen, and the main reason is that I was tired when I wrote it and I needed 2 hours of exploring and rewriting the code to reveal it.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was because a typo.

I had something like

```
struct SomethingStrcut { /* stuff */ };

typedef struct SomethingStruct smth;
```

Notice how the name of the structure is not the same one as the type definition.

I misspelled `struct` to `strcut`.

Look into your code and see wether you have some typos.